# Actualizar un campo fecha de una tabla con valores de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Hola mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo 2 tablas, una que muestra un listado de chips con su fecha de creación y la última fecha en que se realizó una acción con el mismo(ultima_modificacion). La otra tabla muestra un listado con todas las acciones que se realizan con los chips y la fecha en que se realizaron. Lo que necesito lograr es una consulta que me actualize el campo ultima_modificacion de cada chip a partir de la fecha de la ultima acción que se realizo con cada uno. En el ejemplo se puede observar que en los 2 primeros registros de la tabla chip las fechas de modificación son las mismas que las ultimas acciones realizadas con esos dos chips(Venta_a_local)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
update chip
 set chip.ultima_modificacion=(SELECT MAX(Fecha_hora) 
                    FROM historia_chip
                    WHERE chip.id = historia_chip.id)
```

Comment: la tabla de historia puede tener varios registros con el mismo id_chip,por tanto habria que actualizarla solo con la fecha del ultima accion realizada con ese chip

Comment: Perdona, tienes razón, no había visto bien la tabla.

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer eso debes hacer un disparador (Triggers) que cuando se inserte un registro en historia_chip se actualice el campo ultima_modificacion de la tabla chip con el valor del campo fecha_hora de esta manera garantizas que se realice cuando debe y con el valor que debe.

seria algo asi:

**CREATE TRIGGER** actualizar_fecha **AFTER INSERT ON** historia_chip 
**FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    UPDATE** chip **SET** ultima_modificacion=**NEW**.fecha_hora **WHERE** id_chip=**NEW**.id_chip;
**END;**

Comment: el tema es que ambas tablas ya tienen registros insertados, y antes esa fecha de modificacion no se estaba usando,entonces debo actualizar esa columna para cada chip con los datos de esa tabla historia,ya luego si deberia hacer eso que me dices,pero lo primero es lograr actualizar esa tabla chip con los datos que ya estan insertados

Comment: puedes crear el disparador y luego actualizar con la consulta que te sugirió @Ricardo Fernandez así garantizas que todos los registros queden actualizado sin tener que poner la BD offline. Claro que el deber ser es que pruebes todo en un ambiente de prueba para que no tengas ningún error en el código y solo sea pasarlo a producción